# Python how to print without overrides something we input when multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-formatting

I'm trying to make chat like app using python, but if the opposite party send a text while im typing something, it messed up. My codes are like this:

```
import threading
import time
import sys

def printf(str, *args):
    print(str % args, end='')

def printwait():
    global End
    while not End:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(' ')
        print('waiting respond')


def reqinput():
    global End
    while not End:
        name = input("Input your name:")
        End=name=='@end'

End=False

t1=threading.Thread(target=printwait)
t2=threading.Thread(target=reqinput)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('done')
```

when im in middle of typing and then the time sleep expires it messed it up like this:

```
Input your name:waiting respond
im trying twaiting respond
o typwaiting respond
e somethingwaiting respond
 here
Input your name:waiting respond
waiting respond
waiting respond
waiting respond
waiting respond
waiting respond
waiting respond
@waiting respond
end
waiting respond
done
```

while i want it to just print the 'waiting respond' on the upper line or just move whatever im trying to type to after the 'waiting respond'

Comment: You want to keep input and output separate?

Comment: With just `stdin` and `stdout` this is going to be complicated. What you need is separate areas for input and output in your terminal. There are libraries like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) that can assist you.

Comment: yeah, but still on the same console windows